# Error in Google Play transfer frequency - Google BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-play

I want to set **weekly** Google Play transfer, but it can not be saved.
At first, I set **daily** a play-transfer job. It worked. I tried to change transfer frequency to weekly - every Monday 7:30 - got an error:

> "This transfer config could not be saved. Please try again.
> Invalid schedule [every mon 7:30]. Schedule has to be consistent with CustomScheduleGranularity [daily: true ].

I think this document shows it can change transfer frequency:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/play-transfer

Can Google Play transfer be set to **weekly**?

Comment: Hello, the workaround proposed by Ilya Berdichevsky should do the job. To me this looks like an issue related to the web-UI so in case the problem persists I suggest to open a ticket with [GCP Technical Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs#contacting_technical_support) or to open a [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. So true.
If it doesn't work, I'll contact with Google Cloud Support.
Tank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default transfer is created as daily. From the same [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/play-transfer):

> Daily, at the time the transfer is first created (default)

Try to create brand new weekly transfer. If it works, I would think it is a web UI bug. Here are two other options to change your existing transfer:

1. [BigQuery command-line tool](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/working-with-transfers#bq_4): `bq update --transfer_config`
   Very limited number of options are available, and schedule is not available for update.
2. [BigQuery Data Transfer API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.transferConfigs/patch): `transferConfigs.patch` Most transfer options are updatable. Easy way to try it is with [API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.transferConfigs/patch?apix=true#try-it). [Details](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs#resource:-transferconfig) on `transferconfig` object. `schedule` field need to be defined:

> Data transfer schedule. If the data source does not support a custom
> schedule, this should be empty. If it is empty, the default value for
> the data source will be used. The specified times are in UTC. Examples
> of valid format: 1st,3rd monday of month 15:30, every wed,fri of
> jan,jun 13:15, and first sunday of quarter 00:00. See more explanation
> about the format here:
> https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#the_schedule_format
> NOTE: the granularity should be at least 8 hours, or less frequent.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness,  Mr.Berdichevsky.
I think this causes by a bug too.
I will try these options. 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: I read these documents and found it hard to set weekly...

Use bq command : It looks there is no schedule paramerter.

Use API : I think it could be set in detail. But my client own this project, so I could not get auth and other permissions easily. (But, I try this somehow.)

If I got some results, I'll share that here.

I am very grateful to your advice.
Thank you, Mr.Berdichevsky

Comment: try creating a manager account, add client to manager account, setup transfer with manager account